# Rmarkdown : Is it possible to tabset the first headers?

Tags: r, markdown, r-markdown

I know you can tabset the subeaders of a header with the `{.tabset}` option after the title but is it possible to tabset the first headers without 'cheating' and doing something like this ?

```
# {.tabset}

## This is the new 'first' header in tab 1

## This is the new 'first' header in tab 2
```

I like to make full use of the different headers and the first few header levels have a different size in the ToC I'd rather keep for readability.